# Open MPI on an hybrid cluster

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I have set up a two node NFS cluster for running Open MPI applications.
One of them has Intel processors (the master) while the other one has AMD processors. Both are quadcore.
I have installed Open MPI on the same location on both systems (in /use/local)
I am trying to run a simple Hello World example with 4 processes(two on each).
I have tried and tested running these applications locally on both nodes. They run perfectly well.
However, if I pass on a hostfile consisting of these nodes while running (I use mpiexec) it throws errors.
If I compile on Intel, the job does not run on AMD node.
If I compile on AMD, the job does not run on Intel node.

Where could be the problem?

Comment: AMD and Intel processors and different generations of each support different extensions of the basic x86_64 instruction set, such as SSE4, AVX, etc. When compiling you have to specify the most general architecture that is a common subset. Please tell us what processors exactly do you have. That is what `/proc/cpuinfo` tells on each host (especially `flags` and `Model Name` fields). Please update your post with the additional information. The error messages could also be helpful.

Comment: can you edit your post and add the error message ?